# I am using in_app_purchase in flutter .Everything is working except i can't get active subscription in ios i am not using any server

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

For android i get active subscription by this method

```
  InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition androidAddition =
      InAppPurchase.instance.getPlatformAddition<InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition>();

      QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse response = await androidAddition.queryPastPurchases();
```

but for ios, I don't have any function like that to get an active subscription without a server

I used `in_app_purchase` package so i wont have any issue like that but i am stuck on this issue for weeks need help